# Comparing A Time Value Against Database To Stop Repeat Entries

Tags: php, mysql

I am inserting values into a database.

If the time the values were created is less than 24 hours then I insert like this,

```
$stmt = $con->prepare('
    INSERT INTO taggedPlaces
    (id, created_time, place_id, city, country, latitude, longitude, state, street, zip, name)
    VALUES
    (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
');

foreach($graphObject['tagged_places']->data as $data) {
if (time() - strtotime($data->created_time) < 86400) {
      $stmt->execute(array(
       $data->id,
       $data->created_time,
       $data->place->id,
       $data->place->location->city,
       $data->place->location->country,
       $data->place->location->latitude,
       $data->place->location->longitude,
       $data->place->location->state,
       $data->place->location->street,
       $data->place->location->zip,
       $data->place->name
   ));
}
}
```

Everytime I return to the page it takes the same entries and continuously adds them to the database.

I would like to say something like

```
if $data->created_time ==  any created_time value in the DB then don't add this value, 

as well as currently I am doing 

 if (time() - strtotime($data->created_time) < 86400)
```

to make sure it is not older then 24 hours.

How can I add this condition?

Comment: Do you want to prevent duplicates of the created_time or duplicates of the tagged_place? In other words, if a new tagged_place happens to have the same created_time as a previous entry, do you want to prevent it from being inserted? Or do you just want to prevent the tagged_place from being inserted more than once?

Comment: yes im trying to stop the same place being added over and over again. And the only value I can compare is the time. because as long as its a different time even if only off by a second then I know its a new tagged_place

Comment: Is `id` the primary key for `taggedPlaces`? If not, it should be - then just use `INSERT IGNORE` in your query and duplicates will be skipped automatically.

Comment: The id is the one given from facebook, and when I print the array which is in a stdClass Object it shows two different id one for id and one for place_id. then when I enter them in to the database it always enters the same id for both. even on new tagged_places

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1:** *(Recommeded)*

Make `id` the primary key for your table, `taggedPlaces`:

```
ALTER TABLE taggedPlaces ADD PRIMARY KEY(id)
```

Then change your insert statement to use `INSERT IGNORE` which will skip duplicate inserts.

**Option 2:**

Make `created_time` a unique field in `taggedPlaces`:

```
ALTER TABLE taggedPlaces ADD UNIQUE(created_time);
```

Then, again, use `INSERT IGNORE` to skip duplicates.

**Option 3:** *(Not recommeded, but will work)*

Prior to running your insert, perform another query to check if `$data->created_time` is already in the table:

```
$check = $con->prepare('
    SELECT id FROM taggedPlaces
    WHERE created_time = ?   
');

$check->execute(array($data->created_time));

if (count($check->fetchAll()) == 0) {
    // No duplicates found. Proceed...
}
```

Comment: I am assuming the non recommended way is not a good choice because of the amount of time and resources it will take to check the whole database? I really want a solid solution for the long run... The problem is the primary key keeps coming in to the DB the same as the other entries and I can not figure out why. Maybe I should look for a solution to that issue then go with your first suggestion.

Comment: @NichoDiaz Ya, option 3 is not recommended because the same thing should be able to be accomplished much more efficiently using option 1 (or 2). I think you're right that you should probably look for a solution to the ID issue, first.

Comment: Ok thanks a ton again Mark. Ill figure that out then try your first two options.

Comment: My problem was I had the value in the `Mysql table set to int`. I needed to change it to `BIGINT` Thank you for all your help. I have it all working perfectly now.